# SQLite write permissions after .jar generating

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, insert

i have app in java with SQLite database on disk. If i run this app in NetBeans it run without problems. But update get too on .jar file.... it is very interesting....

Connection looks like this:

```
public static Connection connectToDb() {
    // createDirectorieIfNotExist(file);
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\dbsMalwaredb");
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        if (connection != null) {
          //  System.out.println("Otvorená.");
        }
        return connection;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + e.getMessage());
      //  System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But after .jar file generating is there a problem with inserting data into database. I can read and delete data without problems. I tried many versions of JDBC Driver, but it doesnt help. Permissions i have tried to change on disk.

I dont cant why it is so. Please help guys...Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Does the user you are using to logon to the database have the correct permissions?

Comment: yes, it has right permissions